# How to use CanCan in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web

I am working on a project called web portal for billboards management.
My routes.rb looks like:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get "/", to: "main#index"

  get "/login", to: "login#loginpage"

  post "/login", to: "login#create"


  get "/register", to: "register#signup"

  post "/register",to: "register#create"

  get "/owner", to: "owner#ownerdashboard"

  get "/client", to: "client#clientdashboard"

  delete "/logout" , to: "login#destroy"

  get "/addbillboard", to: "addbillboard#add"

  post "/addbillboard", to: "addbillboard#addboard"

  get "/showboards", to: "showboards#showboards"

end
```

Currently i have only two models owner(for users details) and board(for billboards details). I have many controllers which are using these two models. Now i want to integrate cancan with my web app : specific users can access specific pages.My main problem is to prevent guests from accessing owner pages.Like only registered owner can add billboard.
How can i ensure this?
Looking forward for your answers.

Comment: Please note that In typical rails tutorials they generate model and its controller and views by scaffold(same name of model ,controller and view),but its not the case with me. Because my models are used by many pages.

Comment: You're of course welcome to create Rails apps however you like. But these routes are not the Rails way and I wouldn't accept this from a junior or student.  Using the same resource in multiple pages has nothing to do with RESTful design.  As for the rest of the question your basically asking a very low effort question of how to implement an entire feature (authorization) in your application which is off topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

perhaps you should read first, i think it can be understanable

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan

https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/blob/develop/docs/README.md

there is `Ability` class you need to define

perhaps something like this

```ruby
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    can :create, Billboard if owner?(user)
  end
  
  private def owner?(user)
   user.is_owner?
  end
end
```

the implementation is based on your context